# What is difference in inertia of a charged or uncharged object

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose we apply force to two body one charged and other uncharged now the charged body will loose energy in electromagnetic radiation so will acceleration be less in case of charged body if so show it mathematically

Answer (score 0):

This won't get me any points since I will be lazy and simply point you to the [Wikipedia article on electromagnetic mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_mass)